# Storing Doctrine records in the user's session

Tags: php, session, symfony1, doctrine

So I've got a plugin which produces information for me based on a user's id.

This happens in the plugin's module 'pitch':

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $unique_id = $request->getParameter('unique_id');
  $this->user = UserTable::getInstance()->getByToken($unique_id);
  $this->forward404Unless($this->user);
  $this->iplocation=new IPLocation();

  $qualified_offers = new QualifiedOffers();
  $this->creatives = $qualified_offers->applicableTo($this->user);
  $this->match_type = UserDemoTable::getInstance()->getValue($this->user->id, 'match');

  // Put the applicable creatives into the session for later use
  $userCreatives = $this->creatives;
  $this->getUser()->setAttribute('userCreatives', $userCreatives);
}
```

And then I try to call that attribute on the subsequent template (In a different module called 'home' with a different action):

```
public function executePage(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $template = $this->findTemplate($request->getParameter('view'), $this->getUser()->getCulture());
  $this->forward404Unless($template);
  $this->setTemplate($template);
  // Grab the creatives applicable to the user
  $userCreatives = $this->getUser()->getAttribute( 'userCreatives' );
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work at all.

If I try this from the action where $creatives is initially generated:

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('userCreatives', $userCreatives);
$foo = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('userCreatives');
// Yee haw
print_r($foo);
```

I am met with great success. I'm essentially doing this, only from two different controllers. Shouldn't that be irrelevant, given that I've added 'userCreatives' to the user's session?

Comment: It should work. Are you calling $this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->clear() somewhere in between by any chance?

Comment: @Tom That isn't called anywhere in the entire application.

Comment: Hmm... I'd check to make sure that the setAttribute() certainly gets called before the getAttribute(), and I'd also try to pass a simple variable to test. Looks like you're passing array, although it should work anyhow. Var_dumping the getAttributeHolder will also show what exactly is being stored.

Comment: @Tom Perhaps I'm mistaken - But should the attribute be available to the view as $userCreatives? That variable var_dumps as null in the template. Is it that I'm trying to use it improperly?

Comment: @Tom Interestingly I've gotten to a point where I can var_dump $userCreatives from the page action (The controller of the view I'm working with) and the contents are correct, but in the view, the variable is apparently undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Steve, the variable would be available in the view through $sf_user->getAttribute('userCreatives') but not just $userCreatives, unless you separately give this variable a value in your action using $this->userCreatives = 'something'. The fact that it would be available in the actions but not the template doesn't really make sense to me. I'm using this fine in other apps.

Comment: Why are you so absessed with var_dumping, when user session attribute holder is for your convenience in the admin bar?

Comment: @Dziamid: This thread isn't about me, it's about the original poster's problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to store objects as user attributes (i.e., in the session).

From [Jobeet Day 13](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/13):

> You can store objects in the user session, but it is strongly discouraged. This is because the session object is serialized between requests. When the session is deserialized, the class of the stored objects must already be loaded, and that's not always the case. In addition, there can be "stalled" objects if you store Propel or Doctrine objects.

Try storing either `array` or `stdClass` representations of your objects and then loading them back into "full" objects once you retrieve them.

Here's an example that I used on another project:

```
class myUser extends sfGuardSecurityUser
{
  ...

  public function setAttribute( $name, $var )
  {
    if( $var instanceof Doctrine_Record )
    {
      $var = array(
          '__class'  => get_class($var),
          '__fields' => $var->toArray(true)
      );
    }

    return parent::setAttribute($name, $var);
  }

  public function getAttribute( $name, $default )
  {
    $val = parent::getAttribute($name, $default);

    if( is_array($val) and isset($val['__class'], $val['__fields']) )
    {
      $class  = $val['__class'];
      $fields = $val['__fields'];

      $val = new $class();
      $val->fromArray($fields, true)
    }

    return $val;
  }

  ...
}
```